# Tension and Angular Momentum Equilibrium (Exercise)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum

I have this exercise that i'm trying to understand:

A bar AB with a negligible mass is put on an edge, the masses $m_1,m_2,m_3$ are lied to the bar through inextensible wire(negligible mass) and a pulley with a negligible mass  (as the figure shows).
[image: Tension and angular momentum]
The question is to show that, for the bar AB to be in equilibrum, the following equation has to be satisfied: $$m_1(m_2+m_3).L_1=4.m_2.m_3.L_2$$

Say the Movement is happening on the direction the arrow points to :

By applying the second law of motion on each mass we get :

\begin{align}
&(m_1) : P_1-T_1 = m_1.a_1\tag1\\
&(m_2) : T_2-P_2 = m_2.a_2\tag2\\
&(m_3) : T_3-P_3 = m_3.a_3\tag3
\end{align}

And we have $T_1=2T_2=2T_3$ (I'm not so sure about this,following the third law of motion, i got to this.).

And we have $a_2+a_3=2a_1$ (Because the same wire is connected to the three masses, and the part of the wire that is connected to $m_1$ comes from the center of the pulley, relative to an inertial frame.)

going this road didn't get me anywhere, i found that

$$a_1 = g.\frac{(m_1.m_2+m_1.m_3-4m_2.m_3)}{4m_3.m_2+m_3.m_1+m_1.m_2}$$

which setting to it equal to zero gets me this : $m_1(m_2+m_3)=4m_2.m_3$

But why would i set it to zero in the first place? is it because the mass isn't moving? it can be moving, and the masses $m_2$ and $m_3$ would be moving creating an equilibrum. so that's not what's demanded so i think i've gone the wrong way from the start.

Now i know that this equation obviously has to do with the sum of the angular momentum being equal to zero i.e $F_1.L_1=F_2.L_2$, But i don't know which Force are we talking about here? is it $T_1, T_2$ and $T_3$ or the weight of each mass?.

Each end of the bar has a tension applied to it equal to $T_1$ and $T_2+T_3$
And extracting the tensions' formulas from $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ got me nowhere.

The 2nd question is : What is expression of  the force applied on the bar by the edge?
Thanks to anyone who's going to spend his time giving me some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an exercise, just a couple of guidelines:

1. You already know the bar is in equilibrium. So you do not need to    assume that bar edges are accelerating. For example, set *$a_1=0$* in    equation 1.
2. Indeed, the force on the right edge is *$T_2+T_3$*, but you need to    redo your equations (2) and (3) and also figure out the special a-priori relationship between $T_2$ and $T_3$.

As for your 2nd question, the force is tension of string at point of contact. Strictly speaking, this would be $T_4$ on the right side (string to pulley). But you can easily see that $T_4$=$T_3$+$T_2$ when pulley is not accelerating vertically.

Comment: I think $T_2=T_3$. So all i need is $T_1= P_1$  which is the force on the left side, and to calculate $T_2 + T_3$ which is the force on the right side? Oh and i forgot that one of the masses $m_2$ or $m_3$ is going in the opposite direction?

Comment: All three assertions are correct.

Comment: So using the fact that $T_2=T_3$, i can get the acceleration $a_2=a_3$, then get $T_2=T_3$ then the tension on the right side then supposedly the equation will be correct? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple if you remember that the formula for tension in a mass/pulley system is

$\hspace{2cm} T=2 \dfrac{m_2\cdot m_3}{m_2+m_3} g$.

Then the given equation $m_1(m_2+m_3)\cdot L_1=4m_2m_3\cdot L_2$ becomes

$\hspace{2cm}m_1g\cdot L_1=2T\cdot L_2$

which balances the two torques around the fulcrum.